# position div, iframe and scrollable div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position 2 `div`s and an `iframe`. I want the first `div` and the `iframe` to be horizontally positioned, then the 2nd `div` underneath. The 2nd `div` should be a scrollable. I have the following HTML code that does not seem to work. All elements are horizontally floating, and the 2nd `div` is not scrollable. Could I get some suggestions please? Thanks!

https://fiddle.jshell.net/f9L4nny6/

```css
#wrapper div#input, iframe {
    float: left;
}
div#log{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="input">input form here
      </div>
      <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="log" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px; float:bottom">Log will be shown here</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log div has an id, not a class, so you need to style it using `div#log` not `div.log`. The scrollbar shows up properly once that change is made.

To place the log underneath the other two, you could add `clear:left`.

Here's an edited version of your snippet which should be closer to what you're looking for:

```css
#wrapper div#input,
iframe {
  float: left;
}
div#log {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="input">input form here</div>
    <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="log">Log will be shown here</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, just realised that the scrollbar is not showing because the content is too short.

Comment: It's just because there isn't enough content. When the content is small enough to fit the container, `overflow:scroll` makes the scrollbar visible but disabled. If you change it to `overflow:auto`, the scrollbar will be hidden when it isn't needed instead.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper{
overflow: auto;
}

div#log{
float: none;
display: block;
}
#wrapper div#input, iframe {
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
        <body> 
            <div id="wrapper">
              <div id="input">input form here        
              </div>
              <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="log" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px; float:bottom">Log will be shown here</div>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`float:bottom` does not exist . use `float:left;clear:both` instead on `#log`

see bellow

```css
#wrapper div#input, iframe {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="input">input form here
      </div>
      <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="log" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px; float:left;clear:both">Log will be shown here</div>
</body>
```